# Matching algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, matching

I have a list of pencils and a list of erasers. The goal it to check whether or not all the erasers can be put on pencils. An eraser may fit on multiple different pencils. Pencils can have at most 1 eraser.

If I just loop through all the erasers and put them on pencils, I end up with erasers that fit no unoccupied pencils even though there is a solution that has all the erasers on pencils.

What algorithm could I use to figure out a combination that fits all the erasers on pencils?

```
public class Eraser(){
    public boolean matches(Pencil p){
    //unimportant
    }
}

public class Pencil(){
}
```

My attempt

```
public boolean doMatch(List<Eraser> erasers, List<Pencil> pencils){
for (Eraser e : erasers) {
        boolean found = false;
        Iterator it = pencils.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Pencil p = (Pencil) it.next();
            if (e.matches(p)) {
                found = true;
                it.remove();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            return false;
        }
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: What's the matching criteria?

Comment: Is there anything special about those pencils and erasers? It would seem that if there are fewer erasers than pencils, then your answer is "yes", and if there are more erasers than pencils, your answer is "no". So is there a detail that contradicts that?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils It either matches or it doesn't. There is no criteria.

Comment: If anyone can solve this one, it **must** be @ChiefTwoPencils.

Comment: @RealSkeptic All the pencils and erasers are different. Some may match and others may not.

Comment: @user3552325 I believe you're looking for the maximum bipartite matching algorithm.

Comment: Don't try to be efficient.   Just code up a standard backtracking approach.    Cut your teeth on N-Queens first (if you have some time to spare):  http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/backtracking-set-3-n-queen-problem/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution. I doubt it scales at all well. It could probably be made more efficient by starting with the erasers that fit the fewest pencils.

I have not bothered with an `Eraser` class. Here there is one `Eraser` for each index in the `matches` list.

```
private static final class Pencil {
    private final int id;
    private Pencil(int id) { this.id = id; }
    @Override
    public String toString() { return "p" + id; }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pencil p1 = new Pencil(1);
    Pencil p2 = new Pencil(2);
    Pencil p3 = new Pencil(3);
    Pencil p4 = new Pencil(4);
    Pencil p5 = new Pencil(5);
    List<Set<Pencil>> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    matches.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(p1, p2, p5)));     // First eraser only fits these 3 pencils.
    matches.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(p3, p4)));         // Second eraser only fits these 2 pencils.
    matches.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(p3, p5)));         // etc
    matches.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(p1, p2, p4)));
    matches.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(p1, p5)));
    System.out.println(allocate(matches));                     // prints [p2, p4, p3, p1, p5]
}

// Returns null if no solution can be found.
private static List<Pencil> allocate(List<Set<Pencil>> matches) {
    return allocate(matches, new ArrayList<>());
}

private static List<Pencil> allocate(List<Set<Pencil>> matches, List<Pencil> solution) {
    int size = solution.size();
    if (matches.size() == size)
        return solution;
    for (Pencil pencil : matches.get(size)) {
        if (solution.contains(pencil))
            continue;
        List<Pencil> copy = new ArrayList<>(solution);
        copy.add(pencil);
        List<Pencil> result = allocate(matches, copy);
        if (result != null)
            return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can formulate the problem as [Constraint satisfaction problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_Satisfaction_Problem)

The variables would be e.g.

```
X_i=eraser put on pencil i
```

the domains

```
D_i=erasers fitting on pencil i
```

and the constraints are

```
X_i != X_j for i!=j
```

The problem can then be solved with a backtracking algorithm for CSPs. There are many ways to improve the backtracking search with heuristics, for example the "Minimum remaining values" heuristic. A good book is e.g. Russell, Norvig: Artificial Intelligence